# Добавлять запись в Xml с помощью XmlWriter

Tags: c#, xml, uwp

Приложение пишется на UWP.
Я создал файл xml с помощью XmlWriter и записал туда данные. Вопрос в том как потом по мере надобности загружать созданный файл в поток и наполнять его дальше, не затирая предыдущие записи.

```
StorageFolder logfolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Order.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        StorageFile logfile = await logfolder.CreateFileAsync("Order.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        using(IRandomAccessStream writestream = await logfile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            Stream stream = writestream.AsStreamForWrite();
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            using(XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("Orders");
                writer.WriteElementString("Order","First Order");
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndDocument();
                writer.Flush();
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно постоянно дописывать XML данные в поток, то можно использовать фрагментарные записи и чтения XML-я. Для этого используют [XmlWriterSettings.ConformanceLevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.conformancelevel(v=vs.110).aspx) и [XmlReaderSettings.ConformanceLevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.conformancelevel(v=vs.110).aspx) со значением [ConformanceLevel.Fragment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/h2344bs2(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static XmlWriterSettings Settings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment,
            CloseOutput = false,
        };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                AddElement(stream, "First Order");
                PrintStream(stream.ToArray());
                Console.WriteLine();
                AddElement(stream, "Second Order");
                PrintStream(stream.ToArray());
            }
        }

        static void AddElement(Stream stream, String value)
        { 
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, Settings))
            {
                writer.WriteElementString("Order", value);
            }
        }

        static void PrintStream(Byte[] buffer)
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
<Order>First Order</Order>

<Order>First Order</Order><Order>Second Order</Order>
```

Comment: а какой резон может быть в таком способе работы с xml ? MemoryStream все равно оперативку занимает пока вы не закончите все операции записи-чтения. Не проще ли держать в памяти коллекцию объектов и эпизодически ее сериализовать-десериализовать?

Comment: @Bulson Как вы могли видеть работа с XML происходит в `AddElement` и работа происходит с объектом тип `Stream`, т.е. можно работать со всеми объектами которые наследуются от абстрактного класс `Stream`. Объект типа `MemoryStream` в примере выступает в роли mock объекта для тестирования.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы настоятельно рекомендовал забыть все эти XmlWriter-ы и стримридеры и работать с xml через Linq to XML.

Comment: Он не панацея от всего. Особенно когда читаешь гигабайтные файлы.

Answer (score 0):

XML обязан иметь определённую структуру: открывающий тег обязан иметь парный закрывающий. И должен быть всего один корневой элемент. Если просто дописывать в конец файла, то получится несколько корневых элементов, что приведёт к неправильно сформированному XML (и парсеры откажутся с ним работать).

Чтобы избежать этого, есть два подхода.

1. При использовании `XmlWriter`/`XmlReader` нужно создать новый файл на запись, открыть старый файл на чтение и скопировать из него содержимое в новый, добавив в конце (до закрытия корневого тега) дополнительные записи. После чего старый файл можно удалить, а новый переименовать.
2. Работать с XML в памяти. Считать его содержимое, например, в `XDocument`/`XElemnt`, добавить новые элементы, сохранить в прежний файл. Или десериализовать в набор классов с помощью `XmlSerializer`, добавить объекты, сериализовать обратно. Также применим подход из ответа MaLS.

Есть ещё вариант работы с файлом как обычным текстовым потоком: после его открытия переместиться в конец, найти закрывающий тег, перезаписать его новыми элементами, добавить закрывающий тег. Но это неудобно и чревато ошибками.